# Does the amount of downvotes you recieve on a question affect a question-ban eligibility?

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes, upvotes, post-ban

The description on how you receive a question ban is such:

> Stack Exchange has automatic filters in place to ban questions from accounts that have contributed many low-quality questions in the past.

What defines "Low Quality"? How "Low Quality"? Does the amount of downvotes affect this?

For example, if a user receives 10 downvotes in a period of time, does that count as enough to define "Low Quality" questions?

Does the number of questions play a part as well? If I asked 10 questions with a score of -1 each, does that count? Or do I need a minimum of (x) downvotes per question?

Comment: They do affect it, but not nearly as much as upvotes do.

Answer (score 2):

The *actual* algorithm is secret, but downvotes play a substantial role in this. Deleted questions even more so.

The main point here is that one would seek to keep their questions at a net positive score to avoid the question ban.  In theory it shouldn't matter how many questions you ask; if they're all received poorly then it's indicative of the quality of one's participation, and may nudge them closer to the question ban.

Answer (score 1):

The term `Low Quality` is not clear as far as I have seen. For me it means that the post should better be deleted. 
Moreover, Low Quality is a subjective term and although some algorithm already flags a post as low quality based on content and length, people do flag those post as low quality too.

So if most of your questions are flagged as low quality recently either by the automated algorithm or by the community/moderators, then you're at risk of getting a ban.

Low Quality questions have negative scores mostly, but it's not a rule. I have seen Low Quality posts getting upvotes and downvotes on good posts too.

IMO you should focus on asking good questions which have a practical problem and don't ask for opinions. Visit [this excellent checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) of do not ask questions and you're good to go.